# confusion regarding force applied at different angles and work thus done?

Tags: velocity, work

considering  $f=1$ and $s=1$ in the work-energy theorem ,  $W= \cos(\omega)$

this shows that as we increase the angle we do less work for moving an object to the same distance. It also means that for a greater $(\omega)$ , travelling the same distance will produce a lesser velocity in the end.

My question is that for a constant $f$ , how does the above mentioned abstraction apply for a car that is being towed by a car ?

Comment: You may need to clarify what it is you are asking? My understanding of what you are saying is: Work done in a specific direction is f*s*cos(w). Then I don't see what it is you are actually confused by.

Comment: If you wish to understand the forces involved in towing a car then: The engine of the car in the front does work W. This is transferred to both vehicles when accelerating and to lossy mechanisms whilst maintaining a constant speed.

Comment: If you look at his equation f will be force, s is displacement and w is the angle. He is saying work done in a specific direction is force times distance basically.

Comment: @DukeofSam
thanks , you got it right .
should i conclude that the angle of the tow that connects the car and truck  does not matter for the work being done on the car?

Comment: The work done will be constant, the tension will compensate for variation in angle. So for an angle w the tension will be t/cos(w)

Comment: However it's worth noting that if you think about the system there is a stable equilibrium at w=0. Any perturbation in theta will be quickly resolved by the excess tension in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: I will formalize my comments into a comprehensive answer.

Comment: *Paradox* is likely an inappropriate word here. At best, you mean "confusion."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the system of a car towing another car and the relevance of 
\begin{equation}
W = f s cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
to it.
Transfer of energy will look something like:
Energy created by the front car and goes into lossy mechanisms such as air resistance and friction. Any disparity between the two, as you know, will create some acceleration. 
The tow rope connecting the two cars will be at some tension f and some angle w. We can decompose this tension into two components, ones that are parallel and perpendicular to the direction of travel. (edit: the parallel component is the one that you might consider forwards/backwards and perpendicular the one you might consider sideways) The force parallel to the direction of travel is the:
\begin{equation}
fcos(w)
\end{equation}
force you mention. When applying this to the work equation you mentioned it gives the work done in the parallel direction as
\begin{equation}
fsin(w)
\end{equation}
will do for the perpendicular direction. Should the relative positions of the two cars be perturbed such that the angle w is not = 0 then the front car will be doing some work on the back car in the perpendicular direction. All energy is still accounted when you consider all directions, therefore there is no paradox.

Comment: thanks for the answer but please edit t to make it clearer on the perpendicular component part